# kubernetes (AKS) scheduling all pods to same node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kube-scheduler

I have set of pods belonging to different deployments. All are configured to run as single replicas. Further, i have 2 nodes in my cluster. Now, when i try to schedule my pods, all pods get deployed to same node. its very rare that i see my pods are going to another node.

Due to this, my one node is always under memory pressure with utilization near 90% and other node with utilization near 30%. Due to this, if my pods try to consume more than 80% of their limits, they are killed by k8s by saying node does not have enough resources.

How can i spread my pods equally across the nodes? or what could be possibly wrong with my cluster? I have read through topology spread constraints but they only talk about spreading pods belonging to one deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You are right **topology spread constraints** is good for one deployment. There could be many reasons behind that behavior of Kubernetes.

One could be like you have set the **Resource** **request** & **limit** which K8s think is fine to Run both on **Single Node** so it's scheduling both pods on the **same** Node. Or you have not at all set anything which could be another reason too.

Try increasing the **request & limit** of **Deployment** you will the scheduling diff.

Meanwhile, you can also use **Affinity** **(Node/POD affinity)** or **Taints** & **Toleration** is also a good option to separate out the PODs on different available **nodes**. Affinity will work across deployment also.

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
            - zone-east1
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use descheduler together with `LowNodeUtilization` policy to attempt to balance pods out: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler#lownodeutilization

alternatively you can try and use pod anti-affinity and make all pods "hate" each other, that would help with scheduling more evenly.